# Chromium infinitely loading extensions?

Tags: memory, out-of-memory, chromium, raspberry-pi2

I just recently updated my raspberry pi 2 model b using the command `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` shortly after, I opened up chromium to do something, and it came up with the “Aw, snap!” Page. Along with it came a box in the upper right corner of my monitor, which said something about an extension having crashed. This extension I have on other devices, but have never put it on this device. Anyway I was just wondering if there was some way to remove this extension without opening up chromium? Thanks for the help, and my apologies for being such a noob :)

Comment: have you... searched around? https://superuser.com/questions/822429/how-to-start-chrome-without-plugins

Comment: @bolov thanks. Sorry I did look around. Must’ve not been looking for the right thing though. Once again thanks for your help.